# Angular JS validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to validate my text area:

```
<form id="contact_form" name="contactform" ng-submit="submit(contactform)" role="form">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="Message" ng-model="formData.message" ng-trim="false" placeholder="Your message" required="required" rows="8"></textarea>
</form>
```

For max word count, so I added a filter :

```
app.filter('wordCounter', function () {
  return function (value) {
    if (value && typeof value === 'string') {
        return value.trim().split(/\s+/).length;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
  };
});
```

And when this filter is met I print out an error :

```
<span class="help-block" ng-show="(formData.message|wordCounter) > 200">
  Max 200 words please!
</span>
```

But still when I check in my controller `contactform.$valid` is always `true`, how do I make form invalid if the filter wordcounter is more than 200?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom validation directive. With Angular 1.3 [`$validators`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation) it's very easy.

For example, simple one:

```
.directive('maxWords', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
            ngModelController.$validators.maxWords = function(viewValue, modelValue) {
                if (!ngModelController.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
                    return modelValue.trim().split(/\s+/).length <= attrs.maxWords;
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/m3pp71o4/

Comment: thanks, that works! Another newbie question, can I put this directive somewhere on a application level or rootController, rather than specific controller so I can reuse it in other parts of the app

Comment: Yes, of course. You should define this directive in main application module and be able to use it everywhere. It doesn't depend on any specific controller.